# How can I switch tty on a Mac (equivalent of chvt in Linux)?

Tags: macos, terminal, tty

Is there a way to switch between different `tty` from a Mac terminal? This would be an equivalent to the `chvt` command on Linux.

Answer (score -2):

The `screen` command are available for mac. Usage here: [How to use the screen command](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could also use tabs in the default terminal, or install something like iTerm where you can split windows.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to split windows, check out `tmux`, which you can run on macOS and linux terminals.

Comment: Please feel free to elaborate on the reasons for downvoting so that others may share in the wisdom.

Comment: I did not downvote but I get why you are getting downvoted. The problem is that your answer does not answer the question, you are suggesting a tool for other purpose. The question is about `tty` and how to change between them, in linux you have `chvt` but in macOS you don't. `tmux` does not replace or simulates what `chvt` does, that is interacting with the `tty`.